# Phase space of the $n$-vector model

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, spin-models, poisson-brackets

The classical Heisenberg model is described in terms of the three-component unit vector $S_a(x)$, which is a function of position,
$$H=\int d^dx\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a,i}\left(\partial_i S_a(x)\right)^2.$$
$S_a$ obeys Poisson bracket relations like angular momentum
$$ \{ S_a(x), S_b(y) \} =\epsilon_{abc}S_c(x)\delta^{(d)}(x-y),$$
and this implies equation of motion
$$\dot{S_a}=\epsilon_{abc}S_b \nabla^2 S_c.$$

This is fine with me, and I understand phase space as the symplectic manifold $S^2$. But my question is how does this extend to the $n$-vector case where $S_a$ has more than three components? This model is often treated in statistical field theory, but now I would like to describe phase space and define the Poisson brackets so as to get classical equations of motion. We can't just take phase space to be the sphere $S^{n-1}$ because if $n-1$ is odd then obviously this is not a symplectic manifold, and even if $n-1$ is even there is a problem in that $S^{n-1}$ is not Kahler so there is not such an obvious symplectic form.

Comment: As far as I have seen, when people talk about the $n$-vector model, they are OK with just considering the equilibrium state of the model, which is already well-defined without the dynamics: 
Just $Z=\int \mathcal{D}S \exp[-\beta\int d^dx \frac{1}{2}\sum_{a,i}(\partial_iS_a(x))^2]$. Here, $S_a(x)$s are just $n$-component unit vectors, and that's just it. 
I'm not sure, but I guess it could even be the case where dynamics is not consistently definable for certain dimensions. For example, Electro-Magnetism and Maxwell's eq.s become quite wacky in hypothetical higher dimensions.

Comment: @Jun_Gitef17, Thanks for your comments. I thought about it some more since I posted this question. I think you can define classical dynamics for the n-vector model by introducing conjugate momentum to the constrained S fields. In the equilibrium partition function the momentum part of the Hamiltonian is considered to be `integrated out.' But this dynamics is not an extension of the first-order in time dynamics for the classical Heisenberg model in my question.